# Have I solved the following differential equation correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis

[image]
[image]

I'm mostly concerned by the vector notations I used; are they all mathematically correct?

Comment: Looks great! ...

Comment: I upvoted because of your efforts. You should avoid posting pictures and use mathjax instead...